# jQuery Syntax Highlighter don't work on keyup/change/bind with textarea+pre tag

Tags: jquery, syntax

I use [jQuery Syntax Highlighter](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) to make live syntax example show on key change but instead of changing code inside 'pre' tag it will copy itself.

Here is code, but this will not work correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqsyntax/jquery.snippet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqsyntax/css/jquery.snippet.min.css" />

<script>

    $(function() {
        $("textarea").keyup(function(){     // I've tried with change and keydown and click
            $("#classsample > pre").empty();    // I've tried remove this but no sense

            $("#classsample > pre").text( $("textarea.form_code").val() );  // This will copy from textarea text to pre tag
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="addform" class="forms"><textarea name="shortinfo" class="form_textarea"></textarea></div></form>
<div id="source_highlight"><div id="classsample"><pre>- no code -</pre></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A problem is when a key changes without '.empty()' it will code inside source_highlight copy itself and make it duplicates.
It will only work when I remove jquery snippet and on keyup it will change automatically on '' tag. But I want to use this plugin to 'live' change when typing on textarea and recreate on pre tag.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h7wa2/) (work but now call jQuery Syntax, I've imported externall scripts JS)

If I only remove a part of code `$("#classsample > pre").snippet("css",{style:"greenlcd"});` it will work normally as jQuery script.

Comment: Show us your full code. Where do you setup the syntax highlighter?

Comment: A ˙pre˙ code in `source_highlight` is syntax highlighter. Very soon on JS Fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the jsfiddle you created one way is to remove the element on each keyup (since the plugin doesn't provide a destroy method) and append a new one with the relevant code.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7wa2/1/)

```
$(function() {
    var codeContainer = $("#classsample"),
        language = "php";

    $("textarea").on('keyup', function(){ 
        $("pre", codeContainer).remove();
        codeContainer.append('<pre/>');
        $("pre", codeContainer)
            .text($(this).val())
            .snippet(language, {style:"greenlcd"});
    });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Works! It will be remove, and recreate new `pre` tag. That's it.